# Dynamic variable value not updating in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I've run into a bit of a snag I am working with Flask, python, HTML, CSS, and javascript. I am trying to display a different background color via javascript based on the value of a dynamic variable that I'm calling from a python script. The problem is that when I'm calling the dynamic variable within javascript the value stays the same when in reality it shows that it is updating its value. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

here is what I have so far

```
 <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-2">
            <h3 id="CR-1">{{info}}</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-2">
            <h3 id="CR-2">{{info}}</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-2">
            <h3 id="CR-3">{{info}}</h3>
         </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <h3 id="CR-4">{{info}}</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-2">
            <h3 id="CR-5">{{info}}</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-2">
            <h3 id="CR-6">{{info}}</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
    <script>
      if(document.getElementById('CR-1').value = 'Currently Printing'){
            document.getElementById('CR-1').style.background="green";
         }else if(document.getElementById('CR-1').value = 'Not in use'){
            document.getElementById('CR-1').style.background="yellow";
         }
   </script>
```

Comment: please check your if condition..What you are doing is assigning the value as "Currently Printing" .You should be comparing the value using ==

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. It's as if its completely ignoring the if condition now whereas before it would only show one background color despite the dynamic variable physically showing that the value has indeed changed.

Comment: Can you try with "document.getElementById("'CR-1'").innerHTML" instead of value as it is a heading tag

Comment: Since the value of the variable is not updating the innerHTML attribute is overriding the actual value of the dynamic variable. In short, the value is now staying the same and visibly changing :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this in twig, haven't used ninja before but [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x)
indicates that you can.

```
{% set bg = '' %}
{% for info in data %}
    {% if info == 'Not in use' %}
        {% set bg = 'yellow' %}
    {% elif info == 'Currently Printing' %}
        {% set bg = 'green' %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color: {{ bg }}">
        <h3 id="CR-1">{{ info }}</h3>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work either but I am trying different ways of implementing it maybe I'm doing something wrong?